# ASP.net Showing just Date (without time)

Tags: asp.net, date, time, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using VS 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to develop an ASPX page

In my database there is a column of type `Date`.

I stored data in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Didn't put any time there and it doesn't show any time when I view table data in SQL Server.

But in my aspx page, when I pull data using GridView and SqlDataSource...it shows `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` (example- `12/04/2012 12:00:00AM`)

Why does it show the time? How can I remove that time part & show just the date ?

Please help

PS: I'm using .net Framework 4.0 and C#

Comment: The .NET framework doesn't have a `Date` datatype - it's always `DateTime`. But the .NET framework also has great support for specifying a **display format** in a grid to show only the date portion of the `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that MSDN article. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx
You need to set up the DataFormatString string with one of the format strings from the link above :)